# Require Vs RequireJS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am really confused about two things:

1) Require In NodeJS VS RequireJS in Frontend UI (Backbone.js etc). Are they one and the same?  Or do they differ?

2) I wanted to know if requireJS/Require is Async? Or is it synchronous? I've heard that it branches out from AMD (Which is async module). But I heard contradictory statements. I am not sure which one to consider.

I have done googling but none of them are convincing.